# How to Insert data using lookup CRM 365 through Plugin C#

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

i have a lookup "*new_lookuptransactionheader*" in my entity "*new_trialxrmservicetoolkit*". This lookup linked from "*new_transactionheader*" entity. How can i insert data using c# crm plugin?
this mycode:

```
public void InsertDataUsingLookup(XrmServiceContext xrm, Entity entitiy, ITracingService tracer)
{
    new_trialxrmservicetoolkit trial = new new_trialxrmservicetoolkit();
    trial.new_name = "testplugin";
    trial.new_LookupTransactionHeader = null; //this is i don't know how to get value from new_LookupTransactionHeader
    trial.new_Notes = "this is test plugin using c#";
    xrm.AddObject(trial);
    xrm.SaveChanges();
}
```

**I updated mycode and this solve:**

```
public void InsertDataUsingLookup(XrmServiceContext xrm, Entity entitiy, ITracingService tracer)
    {
        new_trialxrmservicetoolkit trial = new new_trialxrmservicetoolkit();
        trial.new_name = "testplugin";
        trial.new_LookupTransactionHeader = new EntityReference("new_transactionheader", Guid.Parse("5564B5F0-0292-E711-8122-E3FE48DB937B"));
        trial.new_Notes = "this is test plugin using c#";
        xrm.AddObject(trial);
        xrm.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
trial.Attributes["new_LookupTransactionHeader"] = new EntityReference("new_transactionheader", new_transactionheaderId-GUID);
```

You have to use `EntityReference` like above to setup lookup attribute.

Comment: i'm still don't understand using `new_transactionheaderId-GUID` i pasted in my code but i got error.

Comment: What is the guid you have? What's the error you got?

Comment: my error : the name of `new_transactionheaderId` doesn't exist in curent contect

Comment: new_transactionheaderId-GUID is a foreign key (primary key of another record) in trial entity.. take the record id from CRM UI. This is basic, spend some time to learn the basics.

Comment: Once got the guid, Then assign in place of new_transactionheaderId-GUID

Comment: do have any another reference suggestion that how to get guid ? i am still in new of crm

Comment: https://arunpotti.wordpress.com/2016/07/10/how-to-get-guid-of-the-record-in-crm-online/comment-page-1/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154190/discussion-between-aminvincent-and-arun-vinoth).

Comment: `trial.Attributes["new_LookupTransactionHeader"] = new EntityReference("new_transactionheader", Guid.Parse("5564B5F0-0292-E711-8122-E3FE48DB937B"));`